# python type error string and nonetype

Tags: python

I am writing a program using two None-types and for one of them I get an error. Here is the program:

```
largest = None
smallest =None
while True:
    num = raw_input("Enter a number larger than 0: ")

    if num == "done" :      
        break

    try:
        float(num)
    except:
        print 'Invalid input'
        continue

    if num < 0:
        print'number is smaller than 0'
        continue
    if num > largest:
        largest = num 
    elif num < smallest:
        smallest = num     
    else:
        continue            

str(largest)
str(smallest)
print ('Maximum is '+ largest)
print ('Minimum is '+ smallest)
```

I always get:

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects on line 23.
```

The answer may be simple, but I'm just a 12 year old beginner. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the beginning, `largest` should be `0`, not `None`. Also, `smallest` should be a very huge number, not `None`

You need to assign `str(largest)` to a variable ie.

```
largest = str(largest)
smallest = str(smallest)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did solve the error, but now I am getting: 

'Minimum is None'   

but  largest is giving the right value.. some help?

Comment: At the beginning your `smallest` variable should not be `None`, it should a very big number, like `smallest = 10000` . In other words, it should be greater than your maximum input.

Comment: That's what I thought at first but what if we're using the programme for number greater than 1000? If None is the smallest number, is there something that is the largest?

Comment: You can use `float('inf')`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that when you compare `num > largest` you're initially comparing `num > None` which will be false. You are also comparing `num < None` for smallest which will also be false. Therefore when you append it to the end of the string with `'Maximum is '+ largest` you are trying to append the None object, which can't be concatenated to strings.

To fix this you have to change your if checks to say

```
if (largest is None) or (num > largest):
```

etc.

Then  when you go to print them you can do `'Maximum is '+ str(largest)` to convert the numbers into string representations that can be concatenated with other strings.

Comment: It's actually the other way around, `None` is always smaller than any number in Python 2.

Comment: it should be a TypeError honestly, but w/e

Answer (score 0):

Some of the issues in your code -

1. `str()` / `float()` are not in-place functions, they return the converted object back, you need to assign it back to `num` or `largest`/`smallest` .
2. In Python 2.x, `None` is always smaller than any integer , so `smallest` would always be `None` , you should use `float('inf')` instead of `None` for `smallest` and `float('-inf')` for `largest`. Example -

   ```
   largest = float('-inf')
   smallest = float('inf')
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the first point, but inf doesn't seem to be built-in. I'm using Python 2.7 by the way.

Answer (score 0):

First you don't have to convert to string your numbers you can use like this:

print "Maximum is %r" %smallest

but it might be solve your prolem but this program will not work because you want to compare more than one numbers ("I think") you have to store in an array but I advise to follow [this web site](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/) If you are new :D

Comment: @Yash Mehrotra @ Chad S @ Anand S Kumar @ Ufuk Akoguz Thanks for all your help. I've corrected it and it works like a dream.